# Oracle procedure, How to select a record

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm writing stored procedore in oracle. I'm using Toad 10.6. I wanna result get a record. Passing a parameter, this is id.
Table TTEST
Columns: {ID, VALUE}.
My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GB.TTEST_GET 
(
id NUMBER
)
IS
a NUMBER;
BEGIN
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TESTING PRINT' || 234);
    SELECT ID INTO a FROM TTEST WHERE ID = id;
END TTEST_GET;
/
```

And when i compiled, following error occored.
[Error] ORA-04044 (29:27): PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Comment: Have different name for variable used in the parameter, as it conflicts wits with the column name of the table!

Comment: Not the reason for this error, but gives you wrong results.

Comment: Are there any other objects accessible to this procedure named `TTEST_GET` or `TTEST`? Try running `select * from all_objects where object_name in ('TTEST_GET','TTEST');`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FUNCTION` returning the `NUMBER`, and you call it using a `SQL`. but the return should be one row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GB.TTEST_GET (p_id NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
a NUMBER;
BEGIN
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TESTING PRINT' || 234);
    SELECT ID INTO a FROM TTEST WHERE ID = p_id;
    RETURN a:
END TTEST_GET;
/
```

And call it as,

```
SELECT GB.TTEST_GET(id) FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Comment: I updated my code from your suggested, then following error found:[Error] Syntax check (2: 1): Found:  'RETURN' Expecting: AS  IS   -or-   AUTHID  DETERMINISTIC  PARALLEL_ENABLE

Comment: hope you didnt include the parameters next to the functio name.

Comment: @TugsbayarBuyadaa    Can you please join the chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45760/procedure-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can return the result from a procedure using OUT parameter. pseudo code for that will be as given below

```
           Create or replace procedure GB.TTEST_GET (p_id number, p_a OUT number)
            is
             Begin
                  SELECT ID INTO p_a FROM TTEST WHERE ID = p_id;
             END GB.TTEST_GET ;
```

For your Error, try aliasing the table name with the appropriate schema name.

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: i updated my code. following error found: [Error] ORA-04044 (26: 29): PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Comment: @Tugsbayar: Have you aliased your table name in the procedure? Also can you post the updated code please.

Comment: "p_id number" should be "p_id IN number"